# Aurelia Skeleton-Navigation Will Not Load After Bundling

Tags: bundle, aurelia

So I am using the Aurelia skeleton-navigation starter as recommended.  However, when I run the gulp bundle task the application will no longer load the main UI, it get's stuck on the spinner/loading page.  I found this [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/132) but even after installing the jspm beta it still doesn't seem to be resolved.  Anyone had any luck? For what it is worth, I do not even see an aurelia.js bundle being created in the /dist directory so the 404 certainly makes sense in that respect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a fix, I am not thrilled with it though.  It seems if you run bundle then run gulp watch to start the webserver, that the bundled files get wiped out from the dist folder.  Running gulp watch in one command window and gulp bundle in another results in it working correctly as the bundled js is there at that point.  I hope for a better fix from someone, this seems kind of hacky.

Comment: gulp watch does clean as the first step, that's why your bundle files are deleted. I use gulp export to create a bundle and then I serve it with a real web server, while gulp watch is used during development time. Feel free to modify the existing gulp workflows for your purpose though.

Comment: I figured that was the case just hadn't gotten an opportunity to look at the task yet.